# Find parents of one-to-many with no children

Tags: sql, one-to-many

Say I had the two tables below, how do I find all questions with no (0) answers?

```
question
---------
id
content
```

and

```
answer
------
id
question_id
content
```

ie, `question 1->* answers`

-- Edit --

To add to my question, how would I retrieve count of answers for each question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from question q where not exists (select 1 from answer a where a.question_id=q.id)
```

answer to edited question:

```
select q.id, content, count(a.id)
  from question q
  left outer join answer a
    on q.id = a.question_id
 group by q.id
```

Comment: Hey! Ive edited the answer, could you check the added requirement?

Answer (score 0):

you can find as using below query.

```
Select * from question where id not in (Select question_id from answer)
```

Comment: Hey! Ive edited the answer, could you check the added requirement?

Comment: @zsquare Please provide some more details.

Comment: You could have said `in (Select distinct(question_id) from answer)` to reduce the sub-query result to match with.